# Cannot pass the value from kwargs in POST method django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-generic-views

When I try to pass the value of course_id using perform_create method, It shows this error...

```
ValueError at /course/9f77f4a9-0486-44f3-8bea-4908adb7d3ca/add/
Cannot assign "'9f77f4a9-0486-44f3-8bea-4908adb7d3ca'": "Content.course_id" must be a "Course" instance.
    Request Method: POST
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/course/9f77f4a9-0486-44f3-8bea-4908adb7d3ca/add/
    Django Version: 2.2.5
    Exception Type: ValueError
    Exception Value:    
    Cannot assign "'9f77f4a9-0486-44f3-8bea-4908adb7d3ca'": "Content.course_id" must be a "Course" instance.
```

This is my views.py

```
class ContentAdd(generics.ListAPIView, mixins.CreateModelMixin):
    queryset = Content.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContentSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        saveData = self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        response_data = {}
        response_data["data"] = saveData.data
        response_data["errors"] = {}
        return Response(response_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        id = self.kwargs.get("course_id")
        serializer.save(course_id=id)
```

This is my serializers.py

```
class ContentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Content
        fields = [
            'title',
            'description',
            'serial',
            'file',
            'file_type',
        ]
```

This is my model.py

```
class Content(models.Model):
    content_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    course_id = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="content_course_id", to_field='course_id')
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=gen_pic_path,blank=False, null=False)
    file_type = models.BooleanField(blank=False, null=False)    # content/attachment
    serial = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
```

This is url path

```
path('course/<course_id>/add/', ContentAdd.as_view()),
```

Comment: Try `serializer.save(course_id__id=id)`

Comment: At the moment when you are creating a `Content` do you have your `Course` already created?

Comment: after try this it shows...

**TypeError: Content() got an unexpected keyword argument 'course_id__id'**
@SergeyPugach

Comment: Yes, I already created Course, Then I try to add some contents in that Course using the course_id. The value I wanna to pass using kwargs is already exists in the Course Table.
@SergeyPugach

Comment: @SergeyPugach you mean `serializer.save(course_id_id=id)`. (one _)

Comment: Don't use `_id` on your `ForeignKey` fields. In the django ORM, a `ForeignKey` field returns an instance of the related model, not an id. `content.course_id` in your case is a `Course` not the id of the course. So it would make more sense to call it `content.course`. Under the hoods, Django creates also the `course_id` which is the id. In your case, it created `course_id_id` to be the id. Hence your confusion on how to assign the correct objects.

Comment: Yeah, got it. Thanks @dirkgroten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get your `Course` for saving `Content`

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    id = self.kwargs.get("course_id")
    course = Course.objects.get(id=id)
    serializer.save(course_id=course)
```

Comment: @MinhajulIslam see my comment on your question above. You really should rename your `ForeignKey` to avoid this type of confusion.

Comment: Absolutely agree with @dirkgroten. You should have `course` field in `Content` model, not `course_id`.